# How to get the product of one and every third integer that is less than a given limit starting with 3 - EXCEPT those divisible by 5

Tags: java, for-loop

If the limit be 21. The output should be 18*12*9*6*3*1. This is what I got so far.

```
   public double sumEveryThird(int limit)
{
    double product = 1.0;
    for(int n = 3;n < limit;)  
    {
        if(n%5 != 0)
        {
            product = product*n;
        }
        n = n+3;
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a project Euler exercice?

Comment: `n < 3` this condition seems off...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for(int i = 3; i < limit; i++)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s a method that I believe does what you want.

```
public double findProduct(int limit) { 
    double product = 1;
        for(int n = 3; n < limit; n = n + 3) {
            if (n%5 != 0)
        {
                product = product * n;
            }
       }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: there's a typo in your for loop iteration and the logic is incorrect. youre iterating through 4,7,10 ..etc and youre only using the values that ARE divisible by 5

Comment: still missing the 'n=' in the for loop iteration but the logic looks good now

Comment: I try to input 36. The answer is -1.466221696E9. The correct one should be 1.5713647488E10.

Comment: Added that. Thought I could do it offhand but should’ve thrown it in my ide to make sure. Thanks for proofreading.

Comment: @danleiqian Now this one I don’t get. I must have a misunderstanding of Java loops if n ever reaches a negative number in that loop.

Comment: @C.Peck I changed the int product to double product and it works. I also put the n=n+3 under the if statement.

Comment: @danleiqian I finally tested it and you're right. I don't understand though.  Why does it have to be a double?

Comment: @C.Peck I think if you use int the result will be too big. The int type has range +_2,147,483,647.

Comment: But why does that make any difference?  I still don't understand why because I'm starting the loop at 3 and ending at the smallest multiple of 3 which is less than limit, right?  What am I missing?

Comment: @danleiqian anyway it's working now right? If so go ahead and approve the answer at your convenience.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
int limit = 21;
    int total = 1;
    for(int n = limit; n > 3 ; n = n - 3)  {
        if(n % 5 != 0){
            total *= n;
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: this doesn't achieve the correct answer. You're using the limit number and youre not using 3